# Symfony 2 theming a textarea widget

Tags: symfony, twig, theming

I am having some trouble theming a textarea.

I have created a separate theme file with the following themes:

```
{% block text_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        {% set type = type|default('text') %}
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block textarea_widget %}
    <div class="textarea_widget">
        {#{% set type = type|default('text') %}#}
        {{ block('textarea_widget') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The first block theme works (text_widget), but the second causes the page not to load at all. It works if I change the block line to

```
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
```

but then twig renders a normal text field. According to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views/Form I should be able to use textarea_widget.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{% block textarea_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="textarea_widget">
        <textarea {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>{{ value }}</textarea>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock textarea_widget %}
```

no?

Answer (score 0):

**Recursion alert!**
You're calling the block inside himself! Didn't Twig detect recursion? If not, you could probably create a feature request for getting an error message...

Comment: You are right, I just saw that. Do you know how I can fix it so that the textarea gets themed properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
{% block textarea_widget %}
    <div class="textarea_widget">
        <textarea>{{ value }}</textarea>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

However this doesn't render the widget's attributes (class name etc), but I can live with that.